# Make a hash from two hashes of different size using logical predicate

Tags: ruby, hash, zip

Suppose I have two hashes of settings. the 'defaults' hash is initialized on startup and 'settings' hash is persisted in database. Not all settings have default, and not all settings are persisted e.g. on first startup, meaning these hashes could have different keys. I need to produce third hash 'all_settings', which will have all keys of those two, with settings key value overriding the default one if both are present:

```
all_settings[key] = settings[key] || defaults[key]
```

I've managed to do it with

```
all_settings = {}
defaults.each{|name, value| all_settings[name] = settings[name] || defaults[name]}
settings.each{|name, value| all_settings[name] = settings[name] || defaults[name]}
```

But I feel it's kind of dumb. Is there way to do the same thing using shorter and more conscise syntax?

Comment: @Zach has your answer for your problem, where `settings` determines the value when the two hashes share keys.  More generally (but not for your problem), `merge` can take a block of the form `h1.merge(h2) { |k,v1,v2| ... }`.  If `h1` and `h2` both have the key `k`, with `v1 = h1[k]` and `v2 = h2[k]`, the value return by the block will become the value for key `k` in the merged hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `merge`:

```
all_settings = defaults.merge(settings)
```

... will return a new hash containing all of the key-value pairs from `defaults`, and all of the key-value pairs from `settings`. If any key is duplicated, it will use the value from `settings`.